# JavaFx: How to replace a comma to a dot in TextfieldTableCell

Tags: javafx

What im doing wrong here?

[image]

i tried to use function replace() on my setOnEditCommit, but not work.

```
    clnVt.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("valorVt"));
    clnVt.setEditable(true);
    clnVt.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));
    clnVt.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<GSTabela2, Double>>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<GSTabela2, Double> c) {
            Double valor = c.getTableView().getItems().get(c.getTablePosition().getRow()).valorVtProperty().getValue();
            String converte = valor.toString().replace(",", ".");
            c.getTableView().getItems().get(c.getTablePosition().getRow()).setValorVt(Double.valueOf(converte));


        }
    });
```

Then i try to use a DoubleStringConverter implemention:

```
public class EstilizadoDoubleStringConverter extends DoubleStringConverter {
private final DoubleStringConverter conversor = new  DoubleStringConverter();

@Override
public Double fromString(String value) {
    try {
        value.replace(",", ".");

        return conversor.fromString(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return -1.0;
}

@Override
public String toString(Double value) {

    try {
        return conversor.toString(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

If i use a the DoubleStringConverter a get -1.0;

So, my question is. How i can replace the comma to dot?

Comment: Maybe a [`NumberStringConverter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.base/javafx/util/converter/NumberStringConverter.html) with an appropriate `Locale` or `NumberFormat` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks very much for help @Slaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix with Slaw Hint.

In my implemention of DoubleStringConverter, i change the

```
private final DoubleStringConverter conversor = new  DoubleStringConverter();
```

to

```
private final Locale local = Locale.getDefault(Category.FORMAT);
private final NumberStringConverter conversor = new  NumberStringConverter(local);
```

so my whole implemention its now like this.

```
public class EstilizadoDoubleStringConverter extends DoubleStringConverter {

private final Locale local = Locale.getDefault(Category.FORMAT);
private final NumberStringConverter conversor = new  NumberStringConverter(local);

@Override
public Double fromString(String value) {
    try {


        return conversor.fromString(value).doubleValue();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return -1.0;
}

@Override
public String toString(Double value) {

    try {
        return conversor.toString(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}